# Error TS1005: ':' expected when attempting to instantiate interface

Tags: typescript

I can not instantiate an interface in Typescript.
I created an Interface, but afterward I can not instantiate it.

Code TS:

```
interface Info {
    name:string;
    age:number;
}

var myInfo: Info ={"med",25};
```

I have get error when compiling:

```
error TS1005: ':' expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myInfo` is not a proper object.  You need to specify keys:

```
var myInfo: Info = { name: "med", age: 25 };
```

Hope that helps you.